# Updating a GUI panel, Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm a Java GUI beginner and am having some trouble getting my panels to update the way I want them to. Basically, when a user clicks one of the buttons in my GUI the shape currently on screen should change to whatever shape corresponds to the button press. My code is below. The problem that the updated shape is being overwritten by the original shape before it can be displayed.

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with my ButtonListeners. I added in print statements to see when the different paint methods are being called, and this is the result after one button click:

RECT
RECT
RECT
ddd
OVAL
RECT

Clearly the update is happening, but is then being overwritten by the original shape! Can someone tell me why this final overwrite happening?!

I've included the FigurePanel class I use for reference.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class miniCADFrame extends JPanel {

    private ButtonPanel buttons = new ButtonPanel();
    private CanvasPanel canvas = new CanvasPanel();

    public miniCADFrame() {
         //Constructor, creates the mother panel
         this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         this.add (canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    //******** BUTTONLISTENER************************
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    //Paint the figure associated with the button click
                canvas.add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.OVAL), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                canvas.revalidate();
                canvas.repaint();
                System.out.println("ddd");

            }
    }

    private class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

        private JButton[] Jbuttons = new JButton[11];
        //Constructor
        ButtonPanel() {

            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4)); 

            // Create buttons to attach to the buttons panel
            Jbuttons[0] = new JButton("Change Colour");
            Jbuttons[1] = new JButton("Up");
            Jbuttons[2] = new JButton("Text");
            Jbuttons[3] = new JButton("Left");
            Jbuttons[4] = new JButton("Enlarge");
            Jbuttons[5] = new JButton("Right");
            Jbuttons[6] = new JButton("Rectangle");
            Jbuttons[7] = new JButton("Down");
            Jbuttons[8] = new JButton("Circle");
            Jbuttons[9] = new JButton("Save");
            Jbuttons[10] = new JButton("Load");

            //Add the buttons to the buttons panel
            for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
                Jbuttons[i].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
                add(Jbuttons[i]);
            }
    }
    }

class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {

        //Constructor
        CanvasPanel() {
            // Create "canvas" to hold a label for the buttons panel along with the button panel itself
             this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
             this.add(new JLabel("CONTROL PANEL"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
             this.add(buttons, BorderLayout.WEST); //add the button panel to the canvas panel

             //test
             this.add(new FigurePanel(FigurePanel.RECTANGLE), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
}
}
```

The FigurePanel class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FigurePanel extends JPanel {

    // Define constants
     public static final int LINE = 1;
     public static final int RECTANGLE = 2;
     public static final int OVAL = 4;

     private int type;

     /** Construct a default FigurePanel */
     public FigurePanel() {
     }

     /** Construct a FigurePanel with the specified type */
     public FigurePanel(int type) {
     this.type = type;
     }

     /** Draw a figure on the panel */
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         //Create blank canvas
         super.paintComponent(g);

         // Get the appropriate size for the figure
         int width = getWidth();//width of the component
         int height = getHeight();//height of the component

        switch (type) {
         case LINE: // Display a single line
             g.drawLine(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10);
             break;
         case RECTANGLE: // Display a rectangle
             g.drawRect((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
             (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
             break;
         case OVAL: // Display an oval
          g.drawOval((int)(0.1 * width), (int)(0.1 * height),
          (int)(0.8 * width), (int)(0.8 * height));
         }
 }
      /** Set a new figure type */
      public void setType(int type) {
      this.type = type;
      }

      /** Return figure type */
      public int getType() {
      return type;
      }

      /** Specify preferred size */
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(80, 80);
      }
}
```

Finally, here is my frame class:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class miniCAD extends JFrame {
    //Constructor for our extended frame class

    public miniCAD() { 

    //Initialize our custom frame
    miniCADFrame frame = new miniCADFrame();    

    add(frame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

     /** Main method */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     miniCAD frame = new miniCAD();
     frame.setTitle("minCAD");
     frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest two possible reasons.

1. Call `canvas.revalidate();` before `canvas.repaint();` to update layout.
2. Check what color is used to draw the panel's content.

Comment: It worked! Sort of. I added a print statement to run every time one of the paint methods is called, and here is the result:                RECT
RECT
RECT
OVAL
RECT

Comment: Why is the final rectangle overwriting things!!? Argggggg

Comment: You actually have two components in the CENTER of the BorderLayout. The add(...) method does not remove the existing component. So you need to remove the original panel first before adding the new panel. Or maybe a better design is to change a property of your class. So instead of just defining the type when you create the panel, you can also have a `setType(...)` method that will allow you to change the shape from a Rectangle to an Oval.

Comment: @camickr I used the second method and it worked! Thanks so much! I was really struggling with this. I do have one more quick question though, could you tell the difference between repaint() and revalidate()?

Comment: @Adam, all components are created with a default size/location of 0, so there is nothing to paint. You use revalidate() to invoke the layout manager so that components are given a size/location based on the rules of the layout manager. The repaint() then paints the components. `I used the second method` - then the revalidate(), repaint() should be part of the setType() method. Although the revalidate() is really only required if you change the size of the shape that you are going to paint.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42626/discussion-between-adam-and-camickr)